# Are fclose(), fprintf(), ftell() thread_safe only in terms of each function itself?

Tags: c, linux

Glibc says fclose()/fopen()/fprintf()/ftell() are thread-safe. But what happens when one thread is writing to or reading the file and another thread is closing the file?

Say I have a function looks like this

```
FILE * f; //f is opened when program starts
int log(char * str)
{
   fprintf(f, "%s", str);
   if (ftell(f) > SIZE_LIMIT) {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if (ftell(f) > SIZE_LIMIT) {
          fclose(f);
          rename(OLD_PATH, NEW_PATH);
          f = open(OLD_PATH, "a");
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   }
}
```

This function is used by multiple threads to write to file. Is it safe,i.e. no crashes? Note that function returning error is fine, my experiments show that the program crashes intermittently.

EDIT:
1. as @2501 pointed out, "The value of a pointer to a FILE object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed", this explains the intermittently crashes.
What if I rewrite the code using freopen?

```
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if (ftell(f) > SIZE_LIMIT) {
          rename(OLD_PATH, NEW_PATH);
          f = freopen(OLD_PATH, "a", f);
      }
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Comment: Code that is concerned about safety should check the result of the various I/O functions.  (Maybe they were left out here for simplification.)

Comment: Even with thread safe functions, you cannot release a resource while another thread is, or might be, using it.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you can use `fputs( str, fp );` instead of `fprintf( fp, "%s", str );`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks, is the performance difference due to the formatting handling overhead in fprintf()?

Comment: @wei *is the performance difference due to the formatting handling overhead in fprintf()?*  Yes, it is.  Depending on the implementation, it can be substantial.  For example, the first 1200 lines or so of the [GLIBC implementation](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.23/vfprintf_8c_source.html) are all macros used in `fprintf()` processing (GLIBC uses `vfprintf()` to implement `fprintf()`)  (Note also in that implementation that passing just a simple string bypasses all that processing - do not use that because it will cause problems if someone passes a string with `%` in it to your `log()` call.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the stream is closed using fclose, the value of the `FILE` pointer is indeterminate. This means that using it causes undefined behavior.

> 7.21.3 Files
>
> 4. ... The value of a pointer to a FILE object is
>      indeterminate after the associated file is closed ...

Since the fprintf call may happen by other threads in the time between the fclose() and open(), when the value of the pointer `f` is indeterminate, the behavior or your code is undefined.

To make the code defined, the fprintf call, and any other call using the pointer, should be locked by the mutex as well.

Comment: ahh, the indeterminate value explains the crash I see. What if I use freopen() like I edited in the orig post?

Comment: @wei *What if I use freopen() like I edited in the orig post?*  That might be even worse, depending on the implementation.  I don't see any guarantee in the [standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) that mandates `freopen()` maintain an internally-consistent `FILE *` object at all times.  Even if it's mutexed, the implied `fclose()` could invalidate the object out from under any thread in the middle of calling `fprintf()`.  It *might* work, but even if it did, doing so would be implementation-dependent at best and undefined at worst.

Comment: @wei Since freopen first closes the file associated with the stream, before opening it, the behavior is still undefined.

Comment: @AndrewHenle & 2501 thanks, guess I will have to use a rdwr lock before fprintf/fputs()

Comment: @wei Instead of a separate mutex or other lock, you should be able to use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` and wrap the entirety of your `log()` function between them.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html# and, for an explanation and example:  http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Threads.html  Note that if you are running on Linux or Solaris you can set the stream to bypass the internal locking of the `FILE *` object, thus making your entire `log()` call atomic with only one lock/unlock cycle.

Comment: @AndrewHenle hmm...i might not be able to use  flockfile() because the file stream it relies one can be disposed.

Answer (score 3):

Each of those functions locks a mutex associated with the `FILE*`.  So those functions are 'atomic' with respect to the particular `FILE*` object. But once the `FILE*` object is closed, it's invalid for use. So if the `FILE*` gets closed and a another thread tries to use that closed `FILE*`, then you'll have a failure due to trying to write to a closed file.

Note that this is aside from any data race you might have with the `f` variable being changed without synchronizing with other threads. (from the code snippet we see, it's not clear whether there's a race there, but I'm guessing that there probably is).

Comment: I got the impression that writing to a closed file stream would return error, but didnt realize that "f' might point to something thats invalid. What if I use freopen() like I edited in the orig post?

Comment: There's still a possible problem with that scheme if `freopen()` returns an error for some reason.  Otherwise, I think it might be OK.  But I'm really not 100% sure.

Comment: thanks. I looked a bit at glibc's freopen() implementation, it does not free the FILE data, so it holds the filelock the whole time, unlike fclose() which release the lock then frees the FILE structure. but I guess it might be implementation dependent as Andrew in the other answer argued.